# Deleting Empty Folders In a Directory

Tags: python

Lets says I have a list of paths that lead to different folders.

```
folders = [path1, path2, path3, ......, pathn]
```

Is there a quick way to loop through this list of folders, and if there is nothing inside them delete them? Thanks!

Comment: Just try to delete the folder. If it's not empty, that will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through them, calling [`os.rmdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rmdir). It will only work on empty folders, otherwise it throws an `OSError`, which in your case you can safely `except` and ignore via `pass`.

[It is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Comment: Although you should probably re`raise` the `OSError` if errno != `ENOTEMPTY`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly where your list of directories (and for the benefit of people seeing only your question's title, not its tags) comes from, it may be better to call the external `find(1)` program.

```
find directory/ roots/ -type d -empty -delete
```